# How to calculate ticket aging, excluding weekends

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using date created and CURRENT date to calculate the ticket aging.
I am struggling to exclude the weekends.
When using the DOW function, it only exclude weekends on date created field, which does not provide accurate results.

Example of:

```
select CURRENT_DATE - date_created::date AS "Case Aging"
where EXTRACT(DOW FROM date_created::date) <> '0' 
AND EXTRACT(DOW FROM date_created::date) <> '6'
from Tickets;
```

Comment: The WHERE clause needs to go after the FROM part

Comment: So which database are you actually using? Please do not SPAM tags, they are designed to attract the correct audience for your question, not an angry mob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a list of days starting with `date_created` till today and count its elements excluding Saturdays  and Sundays.

```sql
with the_table(date_created) as 
(
 values
 ('2022-03-01'::date), ('2022-04-11'), ('2022-10-01'), ('2022-12-06'::date)
) -- sample data

select date_created, (
   select count(*) - 1 
   from generate_series(date_created, current_date, interval '1 day') g
   where extract(ISODOW from g) < 6
 ) as ticket_age
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a clean answer, I literally had to only change the table.